# State type boost:fusion in boost:odeint

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I want to use `boost::odeint` to solve differential equations for different collections of variables- say of `std::vector` type- in parallel. One solution would of course be to combine all variables into a large vector which is then employed as state variable.

However, I would prefer a more elegant solution like employing `boost::fusion` as a state type which then holds the different vectors. As far as I understood from a [posting](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/A-couple-of-odeint-questions-td4636453.html) and the implementation for a [related problem](https://github.com/ddemidov/gpgpu_with_modern_cpp/blob/master/src/lorenz_ensemble/viennacl_lorenz_ensemble.cpp), there is -in principle- no obstacle in doing so. I only miss a few hints for the concrete implementation- in particular concerning the right specification of

algebra, operations and resizing

required for the creation for example of an error stepper. Which of the existing implementations- e.g. `odeint::fusion_algebra`- can be used directly and what remains to done in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `boost::fusion` compile time containers if fine with the `fusion_algebra` and the `default_operations`, as long as each of its elements support

- Multiplication with a scalar (*)
- Addition and subtraction (+,-)
- Resizing

This is the case for the elementary floating point types, like `double`, `float`, or even `std::complex`. This is also the case for types supporting expression templates like the vector and matrix types from the [MTL](http://mtl4.org), boost::ublas, or vexcl and viennacl. But it is not possible for `std::vector`, since vectors do not implement or overload the appropriate +*-/ operators. In this case you have three possibilities

1. Choose an vector type supporting expression templates
2. Implement a nested algebra which iterates the fusion sequence with fusion's `for_each` and calls the correct `for_each` from the sub algebra
3. Implement a custom operation which iterates over the elements of the fusion sequence.

Note 1: Resizing usually means, that if your type needs resizing you specialize `is_resizable` to a compile time true, for example via

```
template<>
is_resizable< YourType > : boost::true_type { };
```

and specialize `resize_impl<>` and `same_size<>`. Have a look at the default implementations. This is really ease and should be only a one-liner.

Note 2: If you also need step size control and you choose to take a vector type with expresson templates the operator `/` and the function `max` must exist and they must perform element-wise division and element-wise max. This might be tricky to implement. If you need some help feel free to contact us again.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and detailed answer and for providing such a great library. As you guessed correctly I really require step size control and thus the easiest proposal won't work for me. Considering the amount of work required to make this work with boost::fusion, I will probably stick with a combined vector of value_types. Alternatively- is there perhaps an easy way to use valarray a state_type? Valarray does not provide an iterator and might thus not work out of the box?

Comment: I have never used valarrays. It would be interesting to know if is works with odeint. But I would not recommend to use valarrays. They are seldom used. Going for vectors or some advanced vector types from MTL, ublas, Eigen, ... is usually the better alternative.